# Without getting duplicate values merge multiple databases with same schema

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms, mdm

I have two instances and each has 300 Databases, I want to merge all this databases in one Database without getting any duplicate rows. All Databases have same schema.

How can I solve this problem only using T-SQL, don't want to use any tools.

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: What if in a table you get rows with the same id, but different values? How do you decide what values to keep?

Comment: There is a column of Email and Contact no, using this.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Suppose I have a customer table and if I find same values in ID while merging I will remove it matching Phone no or email id.

Answer (score 0):

Use below approach for writing some queries like from different database-
Use StackFinal
Go
select * from stacktest.dbo.tbpovalidation
union 
select * from stack.dbo.tbpovalidation

In above query, stacktest and stack are two different databases.

If you have many tables present in a database, you may use the dynamic query approach using sys database.